# Static HTML: iFrame Tabs - landing page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-iframe

I am using the Static HTML: iFrame Tabs app to use to design landing pages for several businesses. I have designed the landing page in html and it works when I click view as fan and view as non-fan. I have selected to display the same HTML for both fans and non-fans.

Accordingly, I selected the option to set my landing page. As a non-fan I see this tab as my landing page. When a fan comes to the facebook page they are forwarded to my wall.

I remember researching this awhile back and it seemed it was a bug that facebook had yet to address. I recently ran into a business page that worked as a fan and non-fan. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You will get  anyway the wall if you liked once the page. It is a Facebook behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, this is how Facebook works - page fans, when going to your page, are sent to the page wall.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default landing page for all users in your page settings.

[image: settings page]

Hope this helps.